# How can I export Layout or Views as images to visible gallery folder in Android?

Tags: android, image, file, image-processing, save

After searching about "How to save Layout views as images", I've found some solution to save in Internal and External Storage. But It seems the image file created is going to save in some data/data/... folder that is not visible normally. Actually I want the image visible in gallery for the user. I've found some code like below, but I even can't check if the image is created or not:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    String yourimagename = "MyImageFile";
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    File file = new File("/" + yourimagename + ".png");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        content.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But It seems the image file created is going to save in some data/data/... folder that is not visible normally.

The file will be saved where the programmer elects to save it.

> Actually I want the image visible in gallery for the user. I've found some code like below, but I even can't check if the image is created or not

That code will not work on any version of Android, as `new File("/" + yourimagename + ".png")` is not going to give you a usable `File`, as it points to a place that you can neither read nor write.

You are welcome to save the image to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Since you want this image to be picked up by "gallery"-type apps, you are best off choosing external storage, then using `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to get the file indexed by the `MediaStore`, since gallery apps will tend to use the `MediaStore` as their source of images.

On the whole, I worry that `getDrawingCache()` will be unreliable. You may be better served telling your root `View` to draw to your own `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the point. Is it possible for you to send an example code, back to me either?

Comment: @Mariox: I do not have sample code of using `getDrawingCache()`, if that's what you mean.